# Set enviromment variable in Maven

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, maven-3

I got an spring boot app with the following `application.properties` setting.

```
#...
spring.datasource.url=${JDBC_DATABASE_URL}
```

When I use an IDE like IntelliJ I can set the environment variable and it woks when I start the app.

But now I want to start my app over the console with maven `mvn spring-boot:run` . How can I set the environment variable here?

Answer (score 10):

From spring-boot version 2 argline key `run.jvmArguments` replaced for `spring-boot.run.jvmArguments`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#run-example-debug . So correct command is:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-DJDBC_DATABASE_URL=jdbc:..."
```

Answer (score 1):

I know its old question, but other answers provide how to set JVM arguments and not environment variables.
You can now set environment variables directly for the by default forked JVM of spring boot via the plugin's configuration in your pom.xml

like so:

```
<project>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <environmentVariables>
                        <ENV1>5000</ENV1>
                        <ENV2>Some Text</ENV2>
                        <ENV3/>
                        <ENV4></ENV4>
                    </environmentVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#run.examples.environment-variables

Answer (score -1):

To pass JVM Arguments to the spring application use:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.jvmArguments="-Dspring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://l‌​ocalhost/mydb?us‌​er=postgres&password‌​=postgres"
```

or

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.jvmArguments="-DJDBC_DATABASE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://l‌​ocalhost/mydb?us‌​er=postgres&password‌​=postgres"
```

See http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/examples/run-debug.html

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
mvn spring-boot:run -DvariableName=variableValue
```

to pass variables into the app via a console

Comment: This way? ```mvn spring-boot:run -DvariableName=JDBC_DATABASE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/mydb?user=postgres&password=postgres``` Its not working...